# Timezone php Symfony2

Tags: php, datetime, symfony

I'm using Symfony2 and I'd like to fetch my dates in function to the user timezone.
So my dates are stored in a database in the server timezone.

I'd like to convert this date to the user timezone before fetching and set the date to the server timezone before saving it into my database.

I'm using Datetime

Thanks or your help

Comment: If you haven't saved the user timezone somewhere, this isn't possible. Php runs on the server and does not know anything about the user

Comment: This is not a problem I can have the user timezone using ajax ajax and session, the answer is how to convert datetimes in function of timezone not repeating myself each time I want to save or fetch a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try somethink like this :

```
$userTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$serverDateTime = new DateTime('2013-08-05 10:10');
$offset = $userTimezone->getOffset($serverDateTime);
echo $offset;
```

Now with the offset you should be able to modify the date like this :

```
$serverDateTime->modify('+'.$offset.' seconds');
```